# How to use JSON to define a check list over all possible cases

Tags: json, data-structures

I'm defining a json to represent a check list.

What I got at the moment is something like this (numbers are id of documents)

1 or 2 or 3

```
[ [ 1, 2, 3 ] ]
```

4 and ( 5 or 6)

```
[ 4, [ 5, 6 ] ]
```

1 and 2

```
[ 1 , 2 ]
```

(1 or 2) and (3 or 4)

```
[ [ 1, 2] , [ 3, 4 ]]
```

(1 or 2) and (3 or 4) and (5 or 6)

```
[ [ 1, 2] , [ 3 , 6] ,  [5, 6 ] ]
```

1 and 2 and ( 3 or 4)

```
[ 1, 2, [ 3 , 4 ] ]
```

but this structure does not cover some cases like below

any two of 1,2,3

(1 and 2) or 3

and maybe more possible cases. Any good suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it explicit, something like:

```
{ or: [1, 2, 3] }
{ and: [4, { or: [5, 6] }] }
{ anyTwo: [ 1, 2, 3] }
...
```

but this is not really very general (even though very human-readable).

Or you can make it into a protocol: `[howmany, options...]`, with `0` being "all", which is very easy to process but a bit hard for humans to read:

```
[1, 1, 2, 3]                          # one out of [1, 2, 3] = 1 or 2 or 3
[0, 4, [1, 5, 6]]                     # all out of [4, one out of [5, 6]]
[0, 1, 2]
[0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4]]
[0, [1, 1, 2], [1, 3, 4], [1, 5, 6]]
[0, 1, 2, [1, 3, 4]]
[2, 1, 2, 3]                          # two out of [1, 2, 3]
[1, [0, 1, 2], 3]
```